# pidgin-blinklight not working with thinkpad_acpi (T430)

Tags: acpi, thinkpad, pidgin

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 on my ThinkPad T430 and want to use the `pidgin-blinklight` plugin.

[The plugin says it needs ibm-acpi](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/net/pidgin-blinklight), but that's depricated as far as I can tell, and `thinkpad_acpi` is loaded by default on my machine:

```
$ sudo lsmod| grep acpi
thinkpad_acpi          81222  0
```

Is there a way to get it working with thinkpad_acpi instead of the ibm one?

Comment: I’m the author of `pidgin-blinklight`, and I cannot use it myself for the reasons mentioned by @Muling. But it seems that the [power LED is controllable](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1250057), maybe I’ll use that as a fallback; I just need a reliable way to detect that the machine is affected by this issue – what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no known possibility to control the thinklight on that laptop, other than off. You can try it when your thinklight is on
 `echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight/device/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight/brightness`. Putting 255 as value to turn it on does not work anymore.

Maybe it has something to do with the new backlight, but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient, but for anyone else who is wondering, the below solution works for me on my T430s under Kubuntu 14.04:

https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/5f87sg/hint_blinking_the_thinklight_with_software_on_new/

In case the reddit link disappears: compile this to an executable called ec_access:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/power/acpi/tools/ec/ec_access.c

Then do

> ./ec_access -w 0x3b -v 16

to switch on, and

> ./ec_access -w 0x3b -v 14

to switch off.

Answer (score 0):

> The plugin says it needs ibm-acpi, but that's depricated as far as I
>   can tell, and thinkpad_acpi is loaded by default on my machine:

Although the kernel module name has changed, the userspace interface has not.  The think-light is still controlled via `/proc/acpi/ibm/light`.  A quick 'strings' check on `pidgin-blinklight` shows that path is still in the binary.

So my educated guess is that it *should* work as is.